# How does a custom hook, which is a function, trigger the re-rendering of another function component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In the [official docs of Custom React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html), one example use of using the custom hook is:

```
function FriendListItem(props) {
  const isOnline = useFriendStatus(props.friend.id);

  return (
    <li style={{ color: isOnline ? 'green' : 'black' }}>
      {props.friend.name}
    </li>
  );
}
```

However, the first time `isOnline` is set, the value should be `null`, because the custom hook has an initial state of `null`, so I think it simply returns `null`:

```
function useFriendStatus(friendID) {
  const [isOnline, setIsOnline] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleStatusChange(status) {
      setIsOnline(status.isOnline);
    }

    ChatAPI.subscribeToFriendStatus(friendID, handleStatusChange);
    return () => {
      ChatAPI.unsubscribeFromFriendStatus(friendID, handleStatusChange);
    };
  });

  return isOnline;
}
```

since `ChatAPI.subscribeToFriendStatus()` is an AJAX call, so when the code finally does `setIsOnline(true)` after, say, 0.7 seconds, how does this actually trigger `FriendListItem()` to be re-rendered?

It makes sense if the state is inside the component, so we can `setData()` and cause the component to be re-rendered. But how does one function cause another function (component) to be re-rendered?

In other words, how can function A gets back a `null` from function B, and something that was set up in function B can magically trigger function A to run?

Answer (score 3):

React provides a few "native" hooks (e.g. `useState`, `useEffect`, etc). All custom hooks are just functions that at some point calls a native hook (or another custom hook which obeys this rule).

Consider these two cases:

```
const A = () => {
   const [s1, setS1] = useState()
   const [s2, setS2] = useState()

   ...
}
```

and

```
const useMyHook = () => {
   const [s2, setS2] = useState()
   // ..maybe do something here
   return [s2, setS2]
}
const B = () => {
   const [s1, setS1] = useState()
   const [s2, setS2] = useMyHook()

   ...
}
```

If you follow the call order you'd see that in both cases we just have two `useState` calls.

In essence custom hooks are "flattened" in the eye of React which only cares about which component is being rendered and the execution order of the native hooks.

Comment: Is this how `useState()` is implemented? (so it is one of its design principles (to make everything look declarative)?) Is there some reference / docs about this? So in other words, function A and call B, which call C, which calls D, and if D has a `useState` hook, its `setTimeout()` and call `setData()` can cause A to run, which in turn would cause B and C and D to re-run? Or is the order: causing C to re-run first, and then B, C, D, and then A, B, C, D, but then this will be inefficient

Comment: I don't know about any documentation specifically, but that's how it observably behaves and React's source-code is open, so you might want to check there. It's always execution-order, the only "special" considerations React takes is "what component am I currently rendering?" and the internals of `useState`, which registers itself in the answer for the previous question, so it can re-render the component when needed. But within the component, "normal" JS rules apply, so top-to-bottom line-by-line execution, and each line is run to completion before the next one starts.

Comment: So I checked. https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-wiles-hbt7c?file=/src/App.js In the console log, it shows that it is always the top function being invoked first, so it is A, B, C, D, instead of "D triggering C to be called, and then triggering B to be called, and then A." It does seem to have the effect that as long as the imperative useEffect is doing its job, at each level, all the hooks are declaratively accurate.

Answer (score 1):

In short, the custom hook does not do anything special, it is just a function. They are just called so because they use the "primitive" hooks and therefore must be used in accordance to the Rules of Hooks.

When React executes a component, it keeps track of which instance it is referred to, and all hooks are attached to that component.

What that means is that effectively, the `useState` is executed in the scope of the component that called `useFriendStatus`, therefore React knows to re-render that component when the state is changed by `setIsOnline`.

Comment: can you see the comment to @thedude pls?